# Cleaning up lines in variable and putting the items in array

Tags: arrays, windows, sorting, powershell

I have a few lines with things, for example it says Haircut on Tuesday evening etc etc.

I'm trying to get PowerShell to firstly trim away everything after `{...` in every line, then skip any line that doesn't have a third word, in this example "Weeding" and "Dishes".

And then I want to apply every first word in every line to a variable `$todo`, the second to `$day` and the third to `$time`.
Then for each `$day` `$time` `$todo` print "~~~~~~" below it.

So this is what I have now:

```
Haircut     Tuesday   Evening  {...
Cleaning Wednesday Morning  {...
Weeding  Thursday           {...
Laundry  Friday    Morning  {...
Dishes   Monday             {...
Yard     Saturday  Afternoon{...
```

This is what I need:

```
Tuesday Evening Haircut
~~~~~~
Wednesday Morning Cleaning
~~~~~~
Friday Morning Laundry
~~~~~~
Saturday Afternoon Yard
~~~~~~
```

The only thing I have so far is this:

```
foreach ($line in $content) {
  $line.Substring(0, $line.IndexOf('{'))
}
```

However that will only output the first line.

Comment: Where does `$content` come from? How do you populate the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Or $content = Get-Content "your file"

$content = @(
    "Haircut  Tuesday   Evening  {...",
    "Cleaning Wednesday Morning  {...",
    "Weeding  Thursday           {...",
    "Laundry  Friday    Morning  {...",
    "Dishes   Monday             {...",
    "Yard     Saturday  Afternoon{..."
)

$content | %{
    $line = $_

    # Strip line and replace multiple spaces with a single instance
    $strip = ($line.Substring(0, $line.IndexOf("{"))).Trim() -replace "\s+", " "
    # Split line on remaining spaces
    $words = $strip.Split(" ")

    if ($words.Count -eq 3) {
        Write-Host "$($words[1]) $($words[2]) $($words[0])"
        Write-Host "~~~~~~"
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I have just one problem, the content is not in an array yet, and it's in a variable called $content like 1 big string, how can I split it?  Can I do something like this? $content = $content.split('{...')   Again sorry for my noobishness

Comment: @Agterbosch ``$content -split "`r`n"`` depending on line terminator

Comment: I honestly don't understand where I'm going wrong with this, but I keep getting this: Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] does not contain a method named 'IndexOf'.
At line:3 char:5
+     $strip = ($line.Substring(0, $line.IndexOf("{"))).Trim() -replace ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @Agterbosch It's not possible that David's code would give you this error unless your input data isn't a string array as in his example. Please stop wasting everybody's time and answer the question I asked before: where does your `$content` come from?

Comment: From the contents of a file, I've got it working somewhat now though, I'm just having trouble with printing out every one of them, the last part now only writes out to me "Tuesday Evening Haircut", the rest is not printed though, so I must still be doing something wrong. The content of $words is also just the words of the first line.

Comment: *"From the contents of a file"* How. Exactly. Do you. Do. That?

Answer (score 2):

[David Brabant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42887244/3829407) does an excellent job showing how to use your string method logic. I would like to show you a pure regex solution to your issue

```
$content | Where-Object{$_ -match "(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)\s*?{"} |ForEach-Object{$matches[1]}
```

Assuming that `$content` is a string array the where clause will only match lines that have 3 words, with variable spacing inbetween, that have a curly brace afterwards. The `$matches[1]` returns the first capture groups with is the words and their spacing. Since the spacing is variable this might not be ideal. In that case you could do something a little different.

```
$content | Where-Object{$_ -match "(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*?{"} |ForEach-Object{
    "Don't forget on $($matches[2]) $($matches[3]) : $($matches[1])"
}
```

If your `$content` is just a string it would probably easy to just split it on newlines like `` $content -split "`r`n" `` but just to show you don't *need* to do it that way.

```
$content | Select-String -Pattern "(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*?{" -AllMatches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty matches | ForEach-Object{
    $_.groups[1].Value
    $_.groups[2].Value
    $_.groups[3].Value
}
```

Splitting on newlines is arguably a simpler approach.